# Setting font size in python turtle module

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use turtle to write the words Hello World at the top of the canvas. By default the font is very small when I use the turtle.write() command. When I try to adjust it, I get the following error: builtins.AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'font'

```
turtle.write("Hello   World!", move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
```

I've tried to change it around a bit but I continue to get the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `font=`

Comment: whackamadoodle3000 If I remove the font=  i get 'positional argument follows keyword argument'

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
turtle.write("Hello World!", move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 8, "normal"))
```

is fine as, except for `"Hello World!"`, these are the default values for the arguments to `turtle.write()`.  The only way I could reproduce your error:

> AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'font'

was to reference `turtle.font` without it being set, something like:

```
import turtle

turtle.write('Hello World!', turtle.font("Arial", 8, "normal"))

turtle.mainloop()
```

which from your description, you didn't do.  This is how I work with `turtle.write()` and fonts:

```
import turtle

FONTSIZE = 18

FONT = ('Arial', FONTSIZE, 'normal')

turtle.write('Hello World!', font=FONT)

turtle.mainloop()
```

I separate the font size out as it's useful to have when you need to position a piece of text precisely in the vertical dimension, e.g. when using a command like `turtle.goto()`.

If none of this helps, provide us with your complete code (including all `import` statements) and the complete error message (i.e. include all the `Traceback` and `File` lines.)

Comment: cdlane thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. That gave me much more insight how to adjust the font and now my code is working how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
t.write("""GAME OVER!
thank you for playing!
Sammy
""", align='center', font=('Arial', 30, "normal"))
```

is the write code.

Answer (score 0):

I found two options to set the fontsize:

1. First Option:

   ```
   import turtle
   turtle.write('Hello, World', font = ['Arial', 16, 'normal'])
   ```

   Instead of using parentheses, you should've used **brackets**
2. Second Option:

   ```
   import turtle
   turtle.write('Hello, World', font = 16)
   ```

   Assign font to the fontsize you want.